# ERROR in 'Angular2SocialLoginModule', function calls are not supported

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have used **angular2-social-login**(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-social-login) for social login and also used **angular-cli**(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for compile.

While I am building production then I am getting below error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'Angular2SocialLoginModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

I have added below code in *`ngModule`*

```
let providers = {
    "google": {
      "clientId": "XXXX",

    },
    "facebook": {
      "clientId": "XXXX",
      "apiVersion": "v2.4"
    }
  };;

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        ...
        Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers),
        ...
    ]
})
```

Comment: make sure you are using latest angular version

Comment: Yes am using 2.4.7 version of angular.

Comment: try after updating  npm

Comment: I have updated `npm`, still i am getting same error.